# How do I find the entrance to SGI Indy?

Tags: b3313

How do I reach the stage [SGI Indy](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/SGI_Indy) in B3313 version 1.0? The wiki says it can be reached by entering a cubed box emitting a beam of light in [Polyginal Chaos](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Polygonal_Chaos). However, I've been wandering the area and have been unable to find the level entrance.

Comment: ... the real challenge would be explaining how to reach that room in the first place. I... will try later, give me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this is based on v0.9. It should be the same in v1.0. If someone wonders why it should be so complicated to find a level... well, you probably never saw this hack.

From the [vanilla main castle lobby](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Vanilla_Lobby), use the wing cap to enter the Princess painting window just above the main door (you *should* be able to find a cap in the left side window in the room that lead to the Princess Secret Slide in the original game).

[image]

Follow the corridor and go thru the door.

[image]

You will find yourself in the Polyginal Chaos area. Now go straight and never turn around.

[image]

go past the small slide and continue straight

[image]

you will find a small "staircase", keep going straight

[image]

The corridor should end with a slope going right, climb that one.

[image]

The beam of light is there, but it is quite not-lighty so... you may have walked past it without even noticing

[image]

All the screens have been taken from [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4O6Bulf81g&t=192s) and reposted here in case the source goes missing.

Comment: Confirming this works on v1.0. Interestingly, the beam of light was much more visible when I played, so they may have brightened it.